Converting List to String in c#
My problem is I am trying to convert a list into a string in a razor page. ie.
asp-for="@(String.Join(',',Model.Character.Weapons))"

or in my character controller:
public IActionResult Upsert(int? id) 
{
    CharacterVM characterVM = new()
        {
            Character = new Character()
        };

    if (id == null || id == 0)
    {
        return View(characterVM);
    }
    else 
    {
        characterVM.Character = _unitOfWork.Character.Get(u=>u.Id==id);
        var weapons = String.Join(',', CharacterVM.Character.Weapons)
        return View(characterVM);
    }
}

However I am not sure what to do once I have String.Join set to a variable.
With the first attempt I get

InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Which I again run into the issue of not sure how to solve this new error. But I feel this method might be a little bit easier to hopefully get around.
With the second option writing in the controller as I stated above I run into the issue of figuring out what to do with the new variable.
To get more insight into the project the github can be seen here https://github.com/bonecrushereb/dndCharacterTracker

Why don't you add a property to CharacterVM with the result of the string.Join? Then you will be able to use this property in the same way you use the other properties.

If you don't need it to be returned use value attribute or place it between tags instead of asp-for -HTH ;)

var weapons = String.Join(',', characterVM.Character.Weapons);

From what I see the characterVM should be lower case("C" to "c") and the ";" is missing at the end of the line.
